# Magento 2 category attribute value returns null

Tags: magento2, category, custom-attributes

**Vendor/Extension/Setup/Patch/Data/CustomAttribute.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Extension\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;

class CreateCustomCategoryAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup, EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            Category::ENTITY,
            'grid_layout',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'label' => 'Grid Layout',
                'input' => 'boolean',
                'sort_order' => 100,
                'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                'global' => 1,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '1',
                'group' => 'General Information'
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

**Vendor/Extension/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="grid_layout">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enable Grid Layout</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**`list.phtml`**

```
$registry = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
$currentCategory = $registry->registry('current_category');
$grid_layout = 0; 
if ($currentCategory) {
    $grid_layout = $currentCategory->getData('grid_layout');
    echo $grid_layout;
}
```

**it return nothing**

can anyone help me about this?

Comment: Have you able to see the option into magento admin category page? and the value are successfully save into database?

Comment: Yes it was saved successfully in DB and changing in the DB

Comment: @JantarMantar I tested your code locally and it works fine in M2.4.6 with Luma theme. Could it be that you simply forgot to flush cache after saving the category? Please also make sure that you edited the correct category.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code.

```
    <?php
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $currentCategory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category information
        $categoryinfo = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($currentCategory->getId()); 
        $grid_layout = $categoryinfo->getData('grid_layout');
        echo $grid_layout;
        
    ?>
```

Comment: tried but same result , it returns nothing

Comment: @JantarMantar I update the code, Kindly check.

Comment: tried that also but no result

Comment: Confirm your file is called on category page or not.

Comment: it is default list.phtml

Comment: I update the code, try that one.